# Html.fromHtml crashes violently in Android 2.1

Tags: android

If I do this in the Android 2.1 emulator:

```
android.text.Html.fromHtml("<p>Sample html</p>");
```

I get this:

```
11-21 20:41:00.557: I/DEBUG(28): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
11-21 20:41:00.557: I/DEBUG(28): Build fingerprint: 'generic/sdk/generic/:2.1-update1/ECLAIR/35983:eng/test-keys'
11-21 20:41:00.557: I/DEBUG(28): pid: 2457, tid: 2457  >>> [my appname] <<<
11-21 20:41:00.557: I/DEBUG(28): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), fault addr deadf00c
11-21 20:41:00.557: I/DEBUG(28):  r0 419c69b4  r1 4186b968  r2 0000bd00  r3 0003a600
11-21 20:41:00.557: I/DEBUG(28):  r4 428dfb68  r5 4186b968  r6 bef169f8  r7 000035f1
11-21 20:41:00.557: I/DEBUG(28):  r8 ad00f380  r9 00001900  10 4186b954  fp 00000000
11-21 20:41:00.557: I/DEBUG(28):  ip 000000f1  sp bef169b8  lr ad012fc4  pc deadf00c  cpsr 40000030
11-21 20:41:00.635: I/DEBUG(28):          #00  pc deadf00c  
11-21 20:41:00.635: I/DEBUG(28):          #01  pc 00012fc0  /system/lib/libdvm.so
11-21 20:41:00.635: I/DEBUG(28):          #02  pc 00019888  /system/lib/libdvm.so
11-21 20:41:00.635: I/DEBUG(28):          #03  pc 00018d5c  /system/lib/libdvm.so
11-21 20:41:00.635: I/DEBUG(28):          #04  pc 0004d3bc  /system/lib/libdvm.so
11-21 20:41:00.635: I/DEBUG(28):          #05  pc 00054e74  /system/lib/libdvm.so
11-21 20:41:00.645: I/DEBUG(28):          #06  pc 00013f58  /system/lib/libdvm.so
11-21 20:41:00.645: I/DEBUG(28):          #07  pc 00019888  /system/lib/libdvm.so
11-21 20:41:00.645: I/DEBUG(28):          #08  pc 00018d5c  /system/lib/libdvm.so
11-21 20:41:00.645: I/DEBUG(28):          #09  pc 0004d6d0  /system/lib/libdvm.so
11-21 20:41:00.645: I/DEBUG(28):          #10  pc 0003a72c  /system/lib/libdvm.so
11-21 20:41:00.645: I/DEBUG(28):          #11  pc 0002be52  /system/lib/libdvm.so
11-21 20:41:00.645: I/DEBUG(28):          #12  pc 00026f7c  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
11-21 20:41:00.655: I/DEBUG(28):          #13  pc 00027c60  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
11-21 20:41:00.655: I/DEBUG(28):          #14  pc 00008cae  /system/bin/app_process
11-21 20:41:00.655: I/DEBUG(28):          #15  pc 0000c2c6  /system/lib/libc.so
11-21 20:41:00.655: I/DEBUG(28):          #16  pc b00018aa  /system/bin/linker
11-21 20:41:00.655: I/DEBUG(28): code around lr:
11-21 20:41:00.655: I/DEBUG(28): ad012fb4 00000000 00000000 00000000 eb000461 
11-21 20:41:00.655: I/DEBUG(28): ad012fc4 e1a00000 e1a00000 e1a00000 e1a00000 
11-21 20:41:00.655: I/DEBUG(28): ad012fd4 e1a00000 e1a00000 e1a00000 00000000 
11-21 20:41:00.655: I/DEBUG(28): stack:
11-21 20:41:00.655: I/DEBUG(28):     bef16978  ad080d34  /system/lib/libdvm.so
11-21 20:41:00.655: I/DEBUG(28):     bef1697c  00000004  
11-21 20:41:00.655: I/DEBUG(28):     bef16980  0000001c  
11-21 20:41:00.665: I/DEBUG(28):     bef16984  ad055c85  /system/lib/libdvm.so
11-21 20:41:00.665: I/DEBUG(28):     bef16988  00000001  
11-21 20:41:00.665: I/DEBUG(28):     bef1698c  00000002  
11-21 20:41:00.665: I/DEBUG(28):     bef16990  00000000  
11-21 20:41:00.665: I/DEBUG(28):     bef16994  00000014  
11-21 20:41:00.665: I/DEBUG(28):     bef16998  afe0df40  /system/lib/libc.so
11-21 20:41:00.665: I/DEBUG(28):     bef1699c  00000002  
11-21 20:41:00.665: I/DEBUG(28):     bef169a0  4186b8ec  
11-21 20:41:00.665: I/DEBUG(28):     bef169a4  428e26aa  /data/dalvik-cache/system@framework@framework.jar@classes.dex
11-21 20:41:00.665: I/DEBUG(28):     bef169a8  4186b8ec  
11-21 20:41:00.665: I/DEBUG(28):     bef169ac  bef169f8  [stack]
11-21 20:41:00.665: I/DEBUG(28):     bef169b0  df002777  
11-21 20:41:00.665: I/DEBUG(28):     bef169b4  e3a070ad  
11-21 20:41:00.665: I/DEBUG(28): #01 bef169b8  40019598  /dev/ashmem/mspace/dalvik-heap/zygote/0 (deleted)
11-21 20:41:00.665: I/DEBUG(28):     bef169bc  bef169f8  [stack]
11-21 20:41:00.665: I/DEBUG(28):     bef169c0  0003a600  [heap]
11-21 20:41:00.665: I/DEBUG(28):     bef169c4  bef169f8  [stack]
11-21 20:41:00.665: I/DEBUG(28):     bef169c8  bef16a78  [stack]
11-21 20:41:00.665: I/DEBUG(28):     bef169cc  ad00f380  /system/lib/libdvm.so
11-21 20:41:00.665: I/DEBUG(28):     bef169d0  0000bd00  [heap]
11-21 20:41:00.665: I/DEBUG(28):     bef169d4  4186bee4  
11-21 20:41:00.665: I/DEBUG(28):     bef169d8  00000000  
11-21 20:41:00.665: I/DEBUG(28):     bef169dc  ad01988c  /system/lib/libdvm.so
11-21 20:41:01.206: D/Zygote(30): Process 2457 terminated by signal (11)
11-21 20:41:01.215: I/ActivityManager(66): Process [my appname] (pid 2457) has died.
```

My first thought was an incompatibility problem with 2.1 so I tried it in 2.3.3 and that works - however this is in fact supposed to work on 2.1 if I'm not mistaken? (Says since API level 1 in documentation).

I've tried it in two separate projects with the same outcome.

Comment: its something else in your code.  i did a project under 2.1 (api 7) that used the same api level emulator.  "Sample HTML" was outputted to the console correctly.  you'll need to post more code

Comment: the only thing i am doing differently is calling .toString on it because i have it like this Log.e("text", android.text.Html.fromHtml("<p>Sample html</p>").toString());

Comment: Agreed, this should work fine. Try creating a fresh 2.1 emulator AVD and see if that changes matters. If you have a sample project that consistently reproduces the problem, post it and the LogCat output from above to b.android.com.

Comment: Have to laugh at title, what version of ADK are you using and are you running this in emulator or on a phone?

Comment: Hey guys thanks for the input, I restarted Eclipse a couple of times and recreated the AVD but still no success.. Then I increased AVD heap size and it worked. Might just as well have been the usual restart everything three times thing though ;)